# Automatic task to fetch new files from ftp and insert them into database (C# and PHP)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, web-services

I am making a website and I need a task (preferably written in C#) to run every hour and look for new/latest files added in the FTP hosting and take their names and insert them into MySQL database from where PHP will read and display them on the website.

I do NOT want the code or how it's done. I have experience in programming languages but not a lot of experience in Web Services (which is what I think this is). I just want some guide lines and know where to start and what do I need.

These are some sample questions that I have and I couldn't find the answer to on the internet. Answers to these and other **useful information I need** to know about this topic would be really appreciated.

- What will make my C# code run every hour?
- Where will I be puttin this .cs code? Somewhere in my website hosting?
- I've bought hosting from hostblast which supports MySQL, PHP, cron job, and many many other services. Can it be done with the hosting I bought? Or do I have to purchase extra things

Comment: why don't write a cron job or schedule task?

Comment: Um... As I said I am not really familiar with these stuff. I did hear about cron jobs and the hosting i bought does support it. However, I do not know in what language cron jobs are written, where they are uploaded? Do we have choice in language of the cron job? if not, can the language that the cron job is written in support what I need? I would really appreciate a bit of details or something that can get me started. Some information or where to begin.

Comment: `Timer at 3600 secs` -> `Connect to ftp` -> `Check all files` -> `Insert-command to db`. Wouldnt an experienced coder get this simple point? Wheres the problem?